# Bash, always check $PWD as part of path?

Tags: shell, usability

Background: One of my colleagues who doesn't come from a Linux background asked me about using `./` before some commands and not others, so I explained to him how `PATH` works and how binaries are chosen to be run.  His response was that it was dumb and he just wanted to not need to type `./` before commands.

Question: Is there a way to easily modify the behavior of the shell such that `$PWD` is always the first item on `PATH`?

Comment: Dumb it may (or may not) be, but every environment has it's quirks, and this is a typical Unix shell quirk.

Comment: It's a security measure. Shells *used* to do this by default (think 1970s), and multi-user systems were widely attacked on account of it.

Comment: *His response was that it was dumb*: said colleague needs to educate his/her own self on this topic. That off-the-cuff answer demonstrates a [PHB-style response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointy-haired_boss): no understanding or appreciation of the underlying system.

Comment: Why not just drop the binaries into `~/bin` and make it part of `PATH` ? This keeps things organized  ,too.

Comment: You know exactly why this was removed was security. Someone could just create a script called `ls` make it executable put it in his home folder and whenever he tries to run `ls` he will then run the adjusted script instead. Which could contain `rm -R /`or a little less hard `rm -R ./`. Explain to your friend that even windows has a `PATH` and that it set as is for a reason.

Comment: @Ziazis on Windows, the current directory is considered regardless of whether it’s part of `PATH` (which is the usual source of such considerations).

Comment: @StephenKitt That was not my point, I just ment the OP was explaining the PATH to the other person which replied it's stupid. PATH by itself exists in Windows aswell, so it's not stupid in general, just because people put more security thinking into it doesn't mean it's "stupid". You could say either more thinking into the security measures or you get pop ups asking you if you really want to run this program. A cleaner way would be adding a ~/bin to the PATH and putting his programs there.

Comment: How often do you run binaries form current dir?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you really want to, you can do this by prepending `.` to your path:

```
export PATH=".:$PATH"
```

However, that’s a bad idea, because it means your shell will pick any command in the current directory in preference to others. If someone (or some program) drops a malicious `ls` command in a directory you use frequently, you’re in for trouble...

Comment: This is an excellent point, although perhaps it would be sufficient to move the . to the end of the path then
export PATH="$PATH:."

Comment: Indeed I remember having `.` at the beginning of your `PATH` was the default for normal users (if I created the user with "sam" on HP-UX, at least; I'm not sure about old SunOS). Later this default was removed for security reasons. If you have the `.` as the last item of your `PATH`, still someone can hope for typical typos.

Comment: @Philippos, yes like the infamous `/tmp/sl` prank scripts to target users with such PATHs. On Debian and derivatives, install the `sl` package to get an idea of how often you type `sl` in place of `ls`.

Comment: No, it is not a bad idea, it is a good one, especially if you're a developer.  Of course, keeping an environment where no  one drops in malicious commands is another good idea.

Comment: @jamesqf, actually, it's a good idea to type out `./` when you want to call commands in the current directory.  Or, if your usual current directory is `/project/under/development/bin`, then add **that** to your `PATH`.  This solves your developer use case.  Putting `.` at the start of your `PATH` is a bad idea, period.

Comment: Technically [the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html#tag_08_03) says you should have an _empty_ entry in PATH to indicate the current directory. I can confirm that `.` works as well in bash, at least. IMO this is a bad idea because it's confusing to have a command "disappear" or change behavior dramatically when you chdir.

Comment: @jamesqf Defense in depth. It's better to avoid vulnerabilities than to try to assume other security is sufficient to prevent them from being dangerous.

Comment: @jamesqf so, never download tar files, you're saying?

Comment: @kojiro the standard says that an empty entry is *supported*, but it’s “a legacy feature” — the standard itself says you should use proper paths (so `.` for the current directory).

Answer (score 15):

Although this is not a direct answer to your question, best practice would be to create a `bin` directory in your home directory as `/home/user/bin`:

```
mkdir -p "$HOME/bin"
echo 'PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"' >> "$HOME/.bashrc"
source "$HOME/.bashrc"
```

Have your personal scripts put in there. The `PATH` would be traversed in the order you define it and execute your personal scripts without the `.` needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the . in the beginning of your PATH variable:

```
export PATH=".:$PATH"
```