# bash: ucbps: command not found

Tags: bash, command-line, command-not-found

How do I solve this?

```
bash: ucbps: command not found
[cbwlskbd@cbl06677app08 ~]$
```

Where to include the path for this?
and how the paths are included

Comment: Probably related to: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400549/bash-always-check-pwd-as-part-of-path/400555#400555

Comment: Could it be a typo for `/usr/ucb/ps` or `ucb/ps` while in the `/usr` directory??

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your path to executable is `/some_path`. The correct way to add this path at the last of the `PATH` environment variable is:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/some_path"
```

And if you want to insert it at the beginning then:

```
export PATH="/some_path:$PATH"
```